# Count transition of records across group(s) over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a re-statement of the problem:
We have the following df and I'm interested in set operations (union or intersection) from month to month to determine things like overlap, count, or nunique items. In addition, nice to have would be to able to define a period (maybe 2-month or quarterly) to do similar analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Time'] = ['7/31/2020','8/31/2020','9/30/2020','10/31/2020','11/30/2020','12/31/2020']
df['dx19']= [{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5},{2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,1}]
df['dx20']= [{11,10,2,3}, {12,3,14,5}, {13,4,2,5},{12,3,4,5}, {1,12,3,14,5}, {5,1,2,6,7,1}]
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%m/%d/%Y')
df.set_index('Time', inplace = True)
```

Here is my current solution, but it seems inefficient so I'm wondering if there is some more elegant solution to do this pairwise comparison or even some way to define a "look-forward" or "look-back" period (previous or future rows) to do different set operations for these groups:

```
from itertools import tee
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
case_list = []
for (idx1, row1), (idx2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
    case = {'p1': idx1.date() , 'p2': idx2.date() ,\
           'p1p2_dx19_intersect' : len(row1[0] & row2[0]), \
            'p1p2_dx20_intersect' : len(row1[1] & row2[1])}
    case_list.append(case)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(case_list)

         p1       p2    p1p2_dx19_intersect p1p2_dx20_intersect
0   2020-07-31  2020-08-31  2   1
1   2020-08-31  2020-09-30  2   1
2   2020-09-30  2020-10-31  3   2
3   2020-10-31  2020-11-30  3   3
4   2020-11-30  2020-12-31  1   2
```

Comment: Please don't post images. Paste everything as text, so that we can also reproduce your example at our ends. Also, what do you mean by `18 to 19` and `19 to 18`?

Comment: Sorry, 18 to 19 is how many ids moved from group 18 to group 19 in the following year and similarly 19 to 18 are the ids that moved from group 19 to 18 for that "year"

Comment: Assuming df is ordered by Year already.  something like this
`df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'year']).groupby('id').group.apply(lambda x: ' to '.join(x.tolist())).value_counts()`?   Although, this only works for 2 years worth of data.  It won't capture changes over multiple years.

Comment: What about using pd.Grouper and setting the frequency to like a year and then applying set and  doing intersection??

Comment: how do you want to track the change over years? do you like to keep track of all changes (2020: 18 -> 19 -> 2022: 18)?  or do you like to know what is changed between any selective 2 years (2020: 18 -> 2022: 18)?

If you have multiple year examples in your data, please add them and also an expected output in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this, you could use the `DataFrame.shift` method to align the two neighboring periods & then evaluate the size. It is critical to ensure that the data is sorted by `Time`, and easier to display both `p1` & `p2` if the index on `Time` is unset.

```py
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.sort_values('Time')
df[[f'{c}_2' for c in df.columns]] = df.shift(-1)
df = df.dropna()
df['p1p2_dx19_intersect'] = df.apply(lambda r: len(r.dx19.intersection(r.dx19_2)), axis=1)
df['p1p2_dx20_intersect'] = df.apply(lambda r: len(r.dx20.intersection(r.dx20_2)), axis=1)
out = df[['Time', 'Time_2', 'p1p2_dx19_intersect', 'p1p2_dx20_intersect']]
out.columns = ['p1', 'p2', 'p1p2_dx19_intersect', 'p1p2_dx20_intersect']
```

`out` now has the desired result:

```
          p1         p2  p1p2_dx19_intersect  p1p2_dx20_intersect
0 2020-07-31 2020-08-31                    2                    1
1 2020-08-31 2020-09-30                    2                    1
2 2020-09-30 2020-10-31                    3                    2
3 2020-10-31 2020-11-30                    3                    3
4 2020-11-30 2020-12-31                    1                    2
```